# Store 100 million vectors in Numpy array. Save and Load at once

Tags: python, pandas, database, numpy, memory

I have 100 million vectors of 768 dimension. I want to use them to train a Faiss index (HNSW PQ) for similarity search. 
Having 100 Million vectors at one place, while saving and loading is memory intensive task that I know. But still is there any way I can do that. Maybe a better data structure, which I can use. 
Below is the code I am using to load .npy (for 6 million only) and using it

```
import numpy as np
vectors = np.load('testing-indexs/combined_vectors.npy')

d = 768 
num_clusters = 768
bits_per_subq = 8

hnsw_pq_index = faiss.IndexHNSWPQ(d, num_clusters ,bits_per_subq)
hnsw_pq_index.train(vectors)
hnsw_pq_index.add(vectors)
```

I know we only have to give representative data for training and can add our data iteratively, but for the reasons that subset of my data cant represent whole 100 million, I want to train whole 100 million and add the same.

Comment: Do you have 307 GB of memory available (assuming float32, i.e. 4 bytes per item in vector: `100_000_000 * 768 * 4 bytes in gb`)?

Comment: That said, if you have a fast enough SSD (and you have that 307 gigabyte `.npy` file), you may be able to use `np.memmap` to semi-transparently read it from disk.

Comment: `tensorflow` has better tools for working with batches, in training and testing.